# How to enable VT-x on HP Pavilion p6387c

Tags: virtualbox, bios, hp-pavilion

So, for some reason, Windows Vista 32-bit with 2GB of RAM needs VT-x on Virtualbox. The thing is, I don't know what BIOS menu to go in, I just know Boot Menu and Advanced startup are not a thing to use. Do I go in Setup? Also, if I were to get a new hard drive, graphics card, power supply, and a new copy of Windows 7 (To install Windows 10 from, it's cheaper) would I need to re-enable it? I have an HP Pavilion p6387c with an Intel Pentium E6300. I bought it in May, 2010. Also, may I add, ever since I got Windows 10, the BIOS screen that has a green hand with all photos flying out of it and the "F12 for Boot menu, F11 for Advanced Startup, ESC for setup and F10 for who knows what only comes up for half a second or so, and my screen is old so only the top half comes up if I'm lucky.

Comment: Does the BIOS setup options look like what is shown [in this HP guide](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-p6000-Desktop-PC-series/4079858/model/4176664/document/c02016194/)? If yes, then there doesn't seem to be any option to toggle VT-x. As for the second part of your question, I don't really get your point.

Comment: That might be so, but I have the Pentium E6300, which [link] (http://ark.intel.com/products/41493/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E6300-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB). But what I want to know, before doing anything, do I go into Setup Utility? Or is it something I need to do somewhere else?

Comment: If you haven't checked out the Setup utility, of course do go and look at what is there. We can't know what there really is despite what the HP guide says.